# belongs_to touch: true not fired on association.build and nested attribute assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

In the [OpenProject](https://github.com/opf/openproject) application we have two models:

[**CustomField**](https://github.com/opf/openproject/blob/413b70a5f6b7685300dbd20c2e6a132b3b297790/app/models/custom_field.rb)

```
class CustomField < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :custom_options, -> { order(position: :asc) }, dependent: :delete_all
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :custom_options
  ...
end
```

[**CustomOption**](https://github.com/opf/openproject/blob/413b70a5f6b7685300dbd20c2e6a132b3b297790/app/models/custom_option.rb)

```
class CustomOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :custom_field, touch: true
  ...
end
```

Then in the [custom field controller](https://github.com/opf/openproject/blob/413b70a5f6b7685300dbd20c2e6a132b3b297790/app/controllers/custom_fields_controller.rb#L66) we modify the options of a custom field via mass assignment and save the record:

```
@custom_field.attributes = get_custom_field_params

if @custom_field.save 
  ...
```

Because of `touch: true` being configured on the `custom_field` association in `CustomOption` I would have expected the custom field's `updated_at` attribute to be updated at this point which does not happen however. The log does not show any SQL requests similar to `UPDATE custom_fields SET update_at = ....`. The changes to the custom options themselves, regardless of whether it is adding a custom option or modifying one, are correctly persisted.

Debugging showed:

- The same erroneous behaviour when using `custom_field.custom_options.build` and a subsequent `custom_field.save`
- The desired behaviour when using `custom_field.custom_options.create`
- The desired behaviour when using `CustomOption.create custom_field: x`
- The desired behaviour when using `custom_field.custom_option[x].destroy`

I know I could work around the problem by defining `after_save` callbacks, but this behaviour really irks me as it was unexpected.

Is the behaviour as outlined above desired and documented? If so, where can I find this information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that if the parent model has any `after_commit` callback (maybe some others), `:touch` stops working when autosaving associated records, even if the callback is not doing anything.

Your `CustomField` model has `after_commit` callback coming from `acts_as_list` gem. This breaks `:touch`.

There was a similar issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26726 . That issue was associated with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but I am sure that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` has nothing to do with it, at least in your case.

**Added by the author of the question (@ulferts):**

Defining `inverse_of: 'custom_field'` on the `custom_options` association in `CustomField` seems to circumvent the problem for unknown reasons.

```
has_many :custom_options,
         -> { order(position: :asc) }, 
         dependent: :delete_all,
         inverse_of: 'custom_field'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @chumakoff, your analysis is spot on. Also thanks for the link. `after_save` callbacks it is, then. I actually had the same suspicion but only deactivated the `acts_as_list` on the child (`CustomOption`).

Comment: Found out that it is possible to circumvent the problem by defining `inverse_of` on the `has_many` association. I send an edit request to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this! I approved the request )